# Regex to replace space between two ' in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a line that looks like this:

```
(267, 'Name Surname')
```

I want to find the space between name and surname, and change it so it will look like this:

```
(267, 'Name', 'Surname')
```

What regex substitution should I make?

Comment: Can there be more spaces than one? Do you want the last one replaced?

Comment: Do all other spaces (those which should not be touched) have a comma before them?

Comment: I'm no regex expert but this worked for me : \((\d{1,10}), '(\w{1,40}) (\w{1,40})'\) with ($1, '$2', '$3') in sublime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'([^' ]+) ([^']+)'` → `'\1', '\2'`

This replaces the first space between single quotes. If you remove the space from first `[]` class, greediness of `+` ensures that the last space between single quotes is replaced.

The first grouping matches anything after a single quote that doesn’t contain single quotes nor spaces. If it was allowed to contain spaces, it will match till the final single quote, but from there it will backtrack as the match needs to be followed by a space.

Answer (score 1):

find : `'(.*?)\s+(.*?)'`

replace with : `'\1', '\2'`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/yC5tF7/1

Comment: This one almost works :) but i have something like 200 rows, and they look like:
    `(277, 'Name1 surname1'),
   (332, 'name2 surname2'),`

So it selects also
    `'),
    (332, '`